# RestKit mapping for specific entity

Tags: ios, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have used common RKObjectManager used for different entity mapping as the following below cod but when i try to make mapping for specific entity couldn't because i have two entity with same keyPath this the problem how i can figured.

```
   // Search  mapping ...
RKEntityMapping *searchEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([ABB class]) inManagedObjectStore: aBBManager.managedObjectStore];

[searchInfoEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"count" : @"count",
 @"total_count" : @"totalCount",

 }];


 // Search Advanced  mapping ...
RKEntityMapping *searchAdvEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([ABB class]) inManagedObjectStore: aBBManager.managedObjectStore];

[searchAdvEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"count" : @"count",
 @"data" : @"dataCount",

 }];

// Search  Descriptor
RKResponseDescriptor *aBBResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:searchEntityMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"locations" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];


 // Search Adv Descriptor
 RKResponseDescriptor *aBB2ResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:searchAdvEntityMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"locations" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `pathPattern` parameter to allow RestKit to know which response descriptor to use when you make a particular request (because you should be using different paths in the URLs for different entities).

If for some reason you can't, you would need to create multiple instances of `RKObjectManager` and use the appropriate one for each different request that you make.